# In React.js, why don't we have to pass parameters event handler functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, arrow-functions

For example, in a rendering **REACT** component, if I needed to pass in an argument it would look like this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.doSomething(**passed in parameter**)}>Press me!</button>
```

This works fine. But how come you don't have to clarify it as the parameter in the fat arrow function first? Like this:

```
<button onClick={(**PARAMETER PASSED IN HERE FIRST**) => this.doSomething(**SAME PARAMETER PLACED HERE**)}>Press me!</button>
```

Comment: Because your param is globally scoped?

Comment: Remember, JSX is a superset of JavaScript, so the same rules apply, with a little more syntax sprinkled on top!

Comment: Yes, usually you should use `(event) => this.doSomething(event, additionalArguments)`. But if your `doSomething` doesn't care, you can of course omit it.

Comment: Thanks for the information  @bergi , that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope):

```
// (a,b) are parameters passed by `Component` to `onClick` handler.
<Component onClick={(a,b) => this.doSomething(d)}/>

// Simple class example
class App extends React.Component {

  doSomething = (a,b) => {
    console.log('a',a,'b',b);
  }

  render() {
//                    onClick={this.doSomething}
    return <Component onClick={(a,b) => this.doSomething(a,b)}/>
  }
}

class Component extends React.Component {

  coolClick = () => {
    this.props.doSomething('hello','world')
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.coolClick}>Active doSomething</button>
  }
}
```

```
// d is a parameter available in the current scope
<Component onClick={() => this.doSomething(d)}

// Simple examples of possible scopes
import { d } from './consts'

const d = 5;

class App extends React.Component {

  doSomething = (x) => {
    console.log('x',x);
  }

  render() {
    const d = 5;
    return <Component onClick={() => this.doSomething(d)}/>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But for more clarification, in this example:
`<ul>
          {this.state.letters.map(letter =>
            <li key={letter} onClick={() => this.handleClick(letter)}>
              {letter}
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>`
Shouldn't you be able to pass in the "letter" parameter as an argument in the arrow function, and this.handleClick should know what it is because it was passed in? 

B/c my confusion is, the function inside the fat arrow should need to know what variable it is using by what was passed in from the actual arrow function parameter.

Comment: @BrianisWinston I don't get what your confusion is, which of the two arrow functions in your snippet you are talking about, and whether it is working as expected for you or not.

Comment: @Bergi I'm referring to the onClick function. Because there is a variable "letter" coming from the map function on the outside, it seems like you would have to pass in "letter" as a parameter in the onClick fat arrow function in order for this.handleClick(letter) to be able to use it. 

Although the documentation clearly says you don't need to pass in a parameter, I would just like clarification for myself.

Comment: @BrianisWinston No. As you said, it's coming from outside (through [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572)), it is *not* coming from a parameter of `onClick`. This means that `onClick()` can be called with no arguments (and it uses the `letter` from the `map` callback parameter) - if you had declared it as a parameter, then the caller of `onClick(…)` would need to provide the value, and that's not what we want here.